# Do not send any Content-type header in cURL

Tags: php, curl, content-type

I'm trying to set the content-type header of my cURL request to null.
For some reason the API I'm trying to use, does not allow a Content-Type.
If I do give a content-type I get a 415 Response.

But it seems that cURL always sents a Content-Type. even if I don't set one.

I tried this:

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
```

or

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: null'));
```

or

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: ""',

));
```

but nothing works.

Anyone any idea?

thank you!

Comment: `'Content-type'` header is only including in POST/PUT requests, i.e. when you sending data to a remote server. Otherwise it shouldn't be included to headers

Comment: Instead of specifying a null content type, can't you send the API something it does expect?

Comment: It expects the content-Type not to be set.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you can't send a cURL request without a content-type header. That is the short answer.
It's just not possible.

If you do not set it your self, it will set the content-type to

```
text/html
```

I was trying to send a file. And finally found that the content-type, for this specific API, should be set to:

```
application/octet-stream
```